# How to get 2 strings out of a Filename - BASH Scirpt

Tags: string, bash, unix, filenames

I need to create an bash script which gets two strings out of a filename.

For Example the Filename is:

```
Test_for_STACKOVERFLOW_dog_2020_10_22.xml
```

I want too save the strings into two Variables.
One Variable with 'STACKOVERFLOW' and the other one 'dog'

But some Files could also be like

```
Test_for_STACK_cat_2020_10_21.xml
Test_for_ANYTHING_bird_2020_10_19.xml
```

Now I need 'STACK' and 'cat'
or
'ANYTHING' and 'bird'

Does anybody have an Idea how I can do this?
The only thing the Files have in common, are that the places of the strings do not change.
So first string will also be after the second _ and the second string is after the third _

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select column 3 and 4 delimited by '_':

```
var1=$(echo $filename | cut -d'_' -f3)
var2=$(echo $filename | cut -d'_' -f4)
```